# Ignite YARN deployment vs vanilla deployment vs embedded deployment

Tags: ignite

With the latest Ignite release (2.4), embedded deployment of Ignite was deprecated, and I refer to the original discussion forum link.

http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Deprecate-IgniteRDD-in-embedded-mode-td24867.html

1) However, it was not clear from the documentation as to what advantage would the YARN deployment have over embedded. If this can please be explained. Wouldn't the YARN deployment have similar shortcomings as embedded?

2) My use case involves using Ignite to create a distributed cache while computing in Spark. Would vanilla deployment of Ignite in a different/same cluster make more sense vs YARN deployment in my spark cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was deprecated because adding and removing server nodes to topology on a whim would lead to expensive and error-prone process of rebalancing caches between nodes. Data may be lost if there are insufficient backups, or will need to be transferred between nodes when this happens. You can also get cluster failures if during a run insufficient nodes are kept alive.

It is much better to run all the needed nodes before work is started, avoid changing topology while work is underway, and kill all nodes once they're no longer needed. That's what YARN deployment tries to do.

Vanilla deployment may make more sense if the lifecycle of Ignite cluster is longer than lifecycle of work you run on MR.